# Limiting call frequency to a static method

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

We have a method which is being called from multiple threads and accesses an external database. In order not to slow down the database for other clients, the calls to this method shall be limited to let's say 1call/second.

I like to keep things simple, so I just did this:

```
private static final Object SYNC_LOCK = new Object();

public static double myMethod(int param1, ...) {
  synchronized(SYNC_LOCK) {
    //do something...
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Now, we are using sonarqube for code analysis and this sleep is considered as a "blocker" bug.
From looking at the code, I can rule out deadlocks. And implementing a kind of token based approach seems a bit much to me.

Would you agree with sonarqube that this code needs to be changed?

Now, we could use for example a thread pool to achieve the same as written below. But the first example seems much more sleek to me.

```
private static ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
private static long lastCall = 0;

public static Double myMethod(int param1, ...) {
    Future<Double> f = es.submit(new Callable<Double>() {
        @Override
        public Double call() throws Exception {
            long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastCall;
            if (diff < 1000) {
                long sleepMillis = 1000 - diff;
                Thread.sleep(sleepMillis);
            }
            //do something...
            lastCall = System.currentTimeMillis();
            return result;
        }
    });
    try {
        return f.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        //handle this
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're making the thread sleep inside the method?

Comment: Yes, because forcing the caller to wait is a bad idea.

Comment: Sleeping isn't computationally expensive, so why should the method sleep when the work is done? The synchronization prevents multiple threads from calling the method at the same time anyway, so that's already limiting it to single-threaded operation. Isn't that enough?

Comment: Kayaman is right, please explain what the use of "1 call/second" is supposed to be. SonarQube is also right, the `Thread.sleep` looks like nonsense there. As SonarQube is not a human, I doubt if it can "understand" the reason, if there is one.

Comment: The sleep is added exactly because it is not computationally expensive. The point of it is, that the burst of requests to this method does not have a bad performance influence on other parts of the application.

Comment: @luk2302: correct, this is a downside. In our case it does not matter though.

Comment: Does the computation take more than 1 second?

Comment: I added a note to the original post clear up why this throttling is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is a band-aid that kind of works. But it creates a bottleneck where only one request can make progress at a time. It's also rough on your clients that they have to pay the time penalty up front, rather than your checking if enough time has gone by since the last request.

Sonarqube is a static analysis tool, all it can do is find patterns in code and apply rules to them. In general the rule of not sleeping with a lock held makes a lot of sense.
When a thread holds a lock obviously other threads are blocked, and when a thread is sleeping it's not doing work, so it is clearly not optimal. In a lot of cases you see programmers adding sleeps as desperate (and ill-advised) attempts to avoid lost-notifications and other bugs, and I think that's what Sonarqube is trying to flag.

First, since hitting the external database is a pain point and you want to relieve the load on it, try caching the results as much as possible.

When you use a ThreadPoolExecutor you get better control over the rate of work by configuring the number of workers, setting up a rejection policy, etc. Once caching reduces the load on the external database enough that you want more than one request at a time, you can tweak the number of worker threads to increase throughput.

Comment: That definitely makes sense to me. I guess changing the implementation to a thread pool does have more benefits than simply removing the sonarqube warning. Maybe we will go that way.

Comment: @user3726374: yeah it is more work this way but could get you farther. also could check out websockets.

Answer (score 0):

Extract business logic in some other method (say `myExpensiveMethod()` below) then think of implementing client side [Rate Limiter](https://reflectoring.io/rate-limiting-with-resilience4j/) (I'm assuming that there is no side effect of concurrent call) -

```
RateLimiterConfig config = RateLimiterConfig.custom()
  .limitForPeriod(1)
  .limitRefreshPeriod(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
  .timeoutDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
  .build();
```

And from `myMethod()` call `myExpensiveMethod()`

```
public static Double myMethod() {

  RateLimiterRegistry registry = RateLimiterRegistry.of(config);
  RateLimiter limiter = registry.rateLimiter("myMethod");
  Supplier<Double> dbQuerySupplier = 
       RateLimiter.decorateSupplier(limiter,
                  () -> myExpensiveMethod());
  return dbQuerySupplier.get();
}
```

Comment: Why ask for client changes and don't use the rate limiter inside that method?

Comment: I mean, this seems like exactly what I am trying to do. But it will definitely be hard to understand for somebody else who just wants to have a quick look.

Comment: @rascio '- I did mention to use rate limiter inside method _or if you can extract business logic in some other method (say myExpensiveMethod() below)_

Comment: @user3726374 - I'm not sure why -  _it will definitely be hard to understand for somebody else who just wants to have a quick look_ ?

Comment: @Pankaj Maybe I am a bit biased towards libraries that I do not know. Probably this could be worth looking into.

Comment: ah sorry I got confused by the mention of creating a new method.
I think that for this use case also the `RateLimiter#acquirePermission()` method of the `RateLimiter` is a good fit (instead of using the Supplier).
By the way resilience4j is a great and widely used library ;)

Answer (score -1):

IMO Simplest approach would be to do something like this (please excuse the pseudo-library calls):

```
public static double myRealMethod() {
  synchronized(SYNC_LOCK) {
    //do something...
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    return result;
  }
}

private static double cachedResult;
private static Somekindoftimestamp cachedResultDate = A_LONG_TIME_AGO;
public static double myMethod() {
  synchronized(SYNC_LOCK) {
    if (cachedResultDate.isTooOldForMyLiking()) {
      cachedResult = myRealMethod();
    }
    return cachedResult;
  }
}
```

One obvious down-side: Some calls to `myMethod()` would take a lot longer than most others.

---

One possible improvement (depending on your application's needs): Have `myMethod()` *always* return the cached result, and create a periodic `Timer` task that calls `myRealMethod()` once per second to update the cached result whether it's wanted or not.

Comment: Introducing caching is not the correct answer to "I've got a computationally expensive method that's called in bursts every hour (and I'm sleeping inside a synchronized block to try to solve it)".

Comment: @Kayaman, Sorry, I missed seeing where OP stated any requirement that would rule out cacheing. The return value obviously must depend on something, but the OP's example gives us no clue as to what. Likewise, OP has given us no clue as to what depends on the return value. I personally have encountered many situations where cacheing would be absolutely the right answer—it computes some summary of the global state of the system, in which many callers are interested—and I have encountered others where it wouldn't work at all. I trust that the OP is smart enough to recognize the difference.

Comment: P.S., Don't forget that the "Answers" here aren't just for the OP. StackOverflow is not a problem-solving service. If my answer doesn't work for the OP, it might well work for somebody else.

Comment: Not if I can get this question closed and deleted for lack of clarity.

Comment: Yeah, sorry this was a bit too much pseudo code on my side. `myMethod` does of course have parameters which are relevant for the computation.